# JSONArray to HashMap

Tags: android, json

I've a JSONArray and I need to get the hashmap with the values, because I need to populate a stream, like twitter done.
What you suggest to do?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgott.
Sorry :)

Answer (score 11):

```
HashMap<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject j = myArray.optJSONObject(i);
   Iterator it = j.keys();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
      String n = it.next();
      pairs.put(n, j.getString(n));
   }
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my situation. Only edit would be to replace the `pairs.add...` with `pairs.put...`.

Comment: I would like to suggest to define the "String n,JSONObject j,Iterator it" out side of the for loop.Because if we have to deal with large number of JSONObjects ,the Stack will get overflow and the program may get slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterator` for getting `JsonArrays`. or use this way

eg. json

```
{
........
........

 "FARE":[   //JSON Array
    {
    "REG_ID":3,
    "PACKAGE_ID":1,
    "MODEL_ID":9,
    "MIN_HOUR":0
    .......
    .......
    .......
    }
      ]
}
```

> ```
> HashMap<String, String> mMap= new HashMap<>();
> for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++) {
>
>    JSONObject j = myArray.optJSONObject(i);
>     mMap.put("KEY1", j.getString("REG_ID"));
>     mMap.put("KEY2", j.getString("PACKAGE_ID"));
>     ............
>     ............
> }
> ```

**note**: For better coding use `Iterator`