# how to get each string separately from HTTP response from service in ANDROID?

Tags: android, json, parsing, http, httpresponse

I have mentioned  response code below.

```
switch(responseCode) {
            case 200:
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if(entity != null) {
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    Log.d("Responce", responseBody.toString());
                }
                break;
            }
```

this code shows the response like below:

```
{"id":9,"name":"babu","role":5,"rights":"IsDelivery","result":"}
```

I want to store each values in separate String. like `Sting id = 3;` `Sting name = babu`.

please give me the solution for this.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307118/jsonarray-to-hashmap

Comment: you might explain what worked for you as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON response and store it to some variables. For example assuming you have a class structure like follow -

```
public class Person{
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String role;
    public String rights;
    public String result;
}
```

Then you can store the response values in this class (in case you don't have string variables already)

The method would be as follows -

```
public Person parseResponse(String jsonString){
    Person person = new Person();
    JsonObject root = new JsonObject(jsonString);
    person.id = root.getString("id");
    person.name = root.getString("name");
    person.role = root.getString("role");
    person.rights = root.getString("rights");
    person.result = root.getString("result");
    return person;
}
```

You can directly save those values in your member variables, instead of saving it into a Person object, but I prefer this way.
Remember that you'd need to handle JsonException here, as in case of any error in json string your app might crash.

PS: To follow encapsulation, you need to make Person class's member field as private and create getters and setters for them. The code here is just for giving you the idea.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 options:

**Easier**:
Create a class with the keys as attributes, like this:

```
class MyEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int roles;
    private String rights;
    // ... other attributes;

    // setters and getters and constructors?
}
```

Then use `Gson` library (either here https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ or in maven repository from **Android Studio**),  and do the following:

```
MyEntity myEntity = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody);
```

**Hard**

Use `JSONObject` to manually get each value:

```
 JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
 int id = mainObject.getInt("id");
 String name = mainObject.getString("name");
 // ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this:

```
 String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


ArrayList<String> S = new ArrayList<String>();

     S = GenerateListCat(responseBody, tt);
```

and the GenerateListCat;

```
private <T> ArrayList<T> GenerateListCat(String result, Type y) {

    ArrayList<T> retData = new ArrayList<T>();

    GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonb.create();
    try {
        JSONArray rslt = new JSONArray(result);
        // Parse Response into our object
        Type collectionType = y;
        String tt = rslt.toString();
        List<T> lst = new Gson().fromJson(tt, collectionType);

        for (T l : lst) {
            retData.add(l);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return retData;
}
```