# How to convert JsonArray to Hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, json

I've been able to get a jsonarray from a json string, but don't know how to put it in a Hashmap with a String that shows the type of cargo and an Integer showing the amount.

The string:

```
"cargo":[   
    {"type":"Coals","amount":75309},        
    {"type":"Chemicals","amount":54454},        
    {"type":"Food","amount":31659},     
    {"type":"Oil","amount":18378}
]
```

Comment: possible this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307118/jsonarray-to-hashmap

Comment: no sorry, already tried that one, some methods don't seem to work with that example

Comment: what did you try and what was the result ?

Comment: I tried the code from the link you gave me. But "JSONObject" and "optJSONObject" couldn't be resolved, maybe because I use javax.json libraries and that guy uses another library?

Answer (score 8):

This fixed it for me:

```
JsonArray jsoncargo = jsonObject.getJsonArray("cargo");

Map<String, Integer> cargo = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsoncargo.size(); i++) {            
    String type = jsoncargo.getJsonObject(i).getString("type");
    Integer amount = jsoncargo.getJsonObject(i).getInt("amount");
    cargo.put(type, amount);
}
```

Comment: Error @getJsonObject method

Comment: should be length() instead of size()?

Comment: How is this going to work? The last item of `type` and `amount` will win, and I don't see how the list is going to be created on the map. I think it should be defined as `Map<String, ArrayList> cargList = new HasMap<>()` then generate the array list `myCargoList` from the JSON Array, and add it to the map using `cargo.put("cargoList", myCargoList)`. Please let me know if this is the correct understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this using the [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
    Map<String, Integer> cargoMap = new HashMap<>();

    JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString, JsonObject.class);
    JsonArray cargo = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("cargo");
    cargo.forEach(item ->
    {
        String type = item.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString();
        int amount = item.getAsJsonObject().get("amount").getAsInt();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(type) || amount != 0) {
            cargoMap.put(type, amount);
        }
    });
```

Where "yourJsonString" is the whole json that contains  the cargo json array.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is

```
    [
        {
            "key": "customerRefNo",
            "value": "A"
        }
    ]
   

 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        params.forEach(e -> map.put(e.get("key").asText(), e.get("value").asText()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new HashMap, and loop through the JSONArray, adding each element to the hashmap.

```
JSONArray allCargo = jsonObject.getJsonArray("cargo");

HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap();

for(Object cargo : allCargo) {
    LinkedHashMap lhm = (LinkedHashMap) cargo;
    hm.put((String)lhm.get("type"), (String)lhm.get("amount"));
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.